# Execute shell command from Python Script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want to execute this command from a python script:

```
iw wlan0 scan | sed -e 's#(on wlan# (on wlan#g' | awk -f > scan.txt
```

I tried like the following

```
from subprocess import call
call(["iw wlan0 scan | sed -e 's#(on wlan# (on wlan#g' | awk -f > scan.txt"])
```

but I get an error

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can try first: `import os` and then: `os.system("iw wlan0 scan | sed -e 's#(on wlan# (on wlan#g' | awk -f scan.txt")`m

Comment: The lack of an argument to `awk -f` is an error.  Presumably you have a script file you want to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.call`:

```
call("iw wlan0 scan | sed -e 's#(on wlan# (on wlan#g' | awk -f scan.txt", shell=True)
```

Note that `shell=True` is not a safe option always.

Comment: `shell=True` runs the command as if you would have entered it into your OS' terminal. That means as long as it's a fixed string which you verified, it's pretty safe. But **never** use `shell=True` if part of the command is not constant but from an insecure source (e.g. user input). Imagine this: `text = input(); call("echo " + text, shell=True)` and the user inputs `I hate you; rm -rf /`

Answer (score 1):

While setting `shell=True` and removing the list brackets around the string will solve the immediate problem, running `sed` and Awk from Python is just crazy.

```
import subprocess
iw = subprocess.check_output(['is', 'wlan0', 'scan'])  # shell=False
with open('scan.txt', 'r') as w:
  for line in iw.split('\n'):
    line = line.replace('(on wlan', ' (on wlan')
    # ... and whatever your Awk script does
    w.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `commands` module is simpler to use:

```
import commands
output = commands.getoutput("iw wlan0 scan | sed -e 's#(on wlan# (on wlan#g' | awk -f scan.txt")
```